# How to make responsive my react component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, jsx

I am getting an error while responsive our web page , don't know how to apply CSS on it.
below I share my UI code please check and please try to give answer as soon as possible. I want to make responsive this cat girl picture and text . in big screen it look perfect.

[image: CAT girl UI]

> PostPage.js

```
import React from "react";

const PostPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="container"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: 10, padding: 5 }}
      >
        <div
          className="header"
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            marginRight: 10,
          }}
        >
          <i
            class="fa fa-home"
            style={{ fontSize: 25, marginTop: 5, marginLeft: 35 }}
          >
            {" "}
            GiveIndia
          </i>
          <h3 style={{ marginBottom: 5, marginLeft: 35 }}>...</h3>
        </div>
        <p style={{ marginRight: 35, marginLeft: 35 }}>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
          five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
          remaining essentially unchanged.
        </p>
        <img
          src="https://live.staticflickr.com/1616/26009626105_26cec46544_b.jpg"
          style={{ width: 700 }}
        />
        <div
          className="message-part"
        >
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <img
                src="http://i.imgur.com/lGq1IXo.png"
                class="w3-circle"
                alt=""
                style={{ width: "50%", borderRadius: "50%", marginLeft: 150,marginTop:-40, backgroundColor:'white',padding:10 }}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <p style={{ marginRight: 230 }}>
                "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
                the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                unchanged."
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use an external library, you can easily apply in-line `css` styles to components using [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop).

```
import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/react'

const color = 'darkgreen'

const customCss = css`
  background-color: hotpink
  &:hover { color: ${color} }
`

render(
  <div css = {customCss}>
    This div has a hotpink background.
  </div>
)
```